# angularjs: controllers with routeproviders

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to load two controllers dynamically using routeproviders in angularjs. But it only returns a blank page instead of showing the default page. What is the error I have done? The code is given below.

**Index.html**

```
<html ng-app="demoController">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
<script>
    var demoController = angular.module('demoController',[]);

    demoController.config = function ($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/customers',{
                controller:'sampleController',
                templateUrl:'template/customers.html'
            })

            .when('/location',{
                controller:'nextController',
                templateUrl:'template/location.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirect:'/customers'});
    });

    var dumpControllers={};
    dumpControllers.sampleController=function ($scope){
        $scope.customers=[
            {name:'John Smith', country:'Denmark', worth:'5000000'},
            {name:'John Lewis',country:'England',worth:'10000000'},
            {name:'Rick Evans',country:'America',worth:'6000000'}
        ];
    };

    dumpControllers.nextController=function ($scope){
        $scope.location=[{city:'Chennai'},{city:'Bangalore'},{city:'Mumbai'}];
    }
    demoController.controller(dumpControllers);
</script>
```

**location.html**

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="loc in location | orderBy: 'city'">{{ loc.city }}</li>
        </ul>
```

**customers.html**

```
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchName">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:searchName | orderBy:'country'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.country }} - {{ cust.worth | currency:"$":2 }}</li>
        </ul>
```

Can help me with this working? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your head after you load angular:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/angular-route.js"></script>
```

and inject the module:

```
var demoController = angular.module('demoController',['ngRoute']);
```

and another problem:

```
        .when('/location',{
            controller:'nextController',
            templateUrl:'template/location.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirect:'/customers'});
};//Removed parenthesis
```

Comment: what does the console say?

Comment: It gives the following error..Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
angular.js:4109 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Still the same. But the console doesn't show any error now